# Plotting data in mysql in Bing Maps

Tags: mysql, bing-maps, pushpin

> How to show lat long data stored from a my sql table on a bing map. Teh goal is to add pushpins to the bing map on the list of locations from the mysql table

Answer (score 0):

If creating a web app, you will need to create a REST service that can connect to your database and expose it as a service so that a web app can connect to it. If you are working with point data, you can have latitude/longitude properties in your data and then loop through it and create pushpins in your apps. If you have more complex shapes (i.e. polygons), consider exposing it as well known text from MySql, and then using the Well Known Text module in Bing Maps to read the shapes.